# How to add column values in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new in rails.I am building a shopping cart application where an user can add items in the cart.So, i have a table `line_items` in MySql database where i have two columns(`cart_id`,`quantity`).I want to add all the `quantities` having same `cart_id`.For example, with `cart_id=5` i have three quantities(2,4,3).So, how do i add all the quantites, which will give me the result 9.

I can do it in Mysql like :

`select cart_id,quantity as total_quantity from line_items where cart_id=5`

But how to do in ROR.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `line_items` table corresponds to a `LineItem` ActiveRecord model, you could do:

```
LineItem.where(cart_id: 5).sum(:quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [SQL alias column](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp):

```
#app/models/cart.rb
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :line_items do
      def total
         sum :quantity
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@cart = Cart.find x
@cart.line_items.total #-> total of quantities
```